# Fresh install of Jupyter gives: TypeError: create.<locals>.Validator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'registry'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, pip, conda, jupyter

I just `pip` installed Jupyter into a conda environment, but when I try to use jupyter notebook, I get this error:

```
(sonar_tf) me@machine:~$ jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 5, in <module>
    from notebook.app import main
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/app.py", line 12, in <module>
    from jupyter_server.base.handlers import JupyterHandler
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_server/base/handlers.py", line 24, in <module>
    from jupyter_events import EventLogger
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .logger import EVENTS_METADATA_VERSION, EventLogger
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/logger.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .schema import SchemaType
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/schema.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .validators import draft7_format_checker, validate_schema
  File "/home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf/lib/python3.11/site-packages/jupyter_events/validators.py", line 44, in <module>
    JUPYTER_EVENTS_SCHEMA_VALIDATOR = Draft7Validator(
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: create.<locals>.Validator.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'registry'
```

Has anyone else seen this? The most relevant packages in my environment are (I think):

```
jupyter-client            8.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              5.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-events            0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-terminals  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab                4.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.25.0                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab_widgets        3.0.5           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
nbclient                  0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 7.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook                  7.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
```

I tried creating a brand new environment with pip, which I then used to install notebook, and this problem didn't occur, so I assume there's some inconsistent package in my sonar_tf environment.

I'm slowly rebuilding this env from scratch with jupyter pip installed early and will be slowly adding my conda (and pip) packages one at a time, but if anyone can pinpoint what my problem is, it might save me from duplicating the error. If it helps, here is the complete environment:

```
(sonar_tf) me@machine:~$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/smgutstein/anaconda3/envs/sonar_tf:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                  2_kmp_llvm    conda-forge
absl-py                   1.4.0           py311h06a4308_0  
aiohttp                   3.8.5           py311h5eee18b_0  
aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
alsa-lib                  1.2.10               hd590300_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.5.0           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0          py311h5eee18b_0    anaconda
arrow                     1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0  
async-lru                 2.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
async-timeout             4.0.2           py311h06a4308_0  
attr                      2.5.1                h166bdaf_1    conda-forge
attrs                     23.1.0          py311h06a4308_0  
audioread                 3.0.1           py311h38be061_1    conda-forge
babel                     2.11.0          py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
beautifulsoup4            4.12.2                   pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
blinker                   1.6.2           py311h06a4308_0  
blosc                     1.21.3               h6a678d5_0    anaconda
bottleneck                1.3.5           py311hbed6279_0    anaconda
brotli                    1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
brotli-python             1.0.9           py311h6a678d5_7  
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0  
c-ares                    1.19.1               h5eee18b_0  
c-blosc2                  2.8.0                h6a678d5_0    anaconda
ca-certificates           2023.08.22           h06a4308_0  
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
cairo                     1.18.0               h3faef2a_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.7.22       py311h06a4308_0  
cffi                      1.15.1          py311h5eee18b_3  
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
click                     8.1.7           py311h06a4308_0  
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
comm                      0.1.2           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
contourpy                 1.0.5           py311hdb19cb5_0  
cryptography              41.0.3          py311hdda0065_0  
cuda-version              11.8                 h70ddcb2_2    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               11.8.0               h6a678d5_0  
cudnn                     8.9.2.26               cuda11_0  
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
dbus                      1.13.6               h5008d03_3    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.7           py311h6a678d5_0    anaconda
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
entrypoints               0.4             py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
expat                     2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    4.2.2                h20bf706_0  
flatbuffers               23.5.26              h59595ed_1    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               h14ed4e7_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
fqdn                      1.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.12.1               h4a9f257_0  
frozenlist                1.3.3           py311h5eee18b_0  
gast                      0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
gettext                   0.21.1               h27087fc_0    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h5eee18b_3  
glib                      2.78.0               hfc55251_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.78.0               hfc55251_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h295c915_3  
gnutls                    3.6.15               he1e5248_0  
google-auth               2.22.0          py311h06a4308_0  
google-auth-oauthlib      0.5.2           py311h06a4308_0  
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
graphite2                 1.3.13            h58526e2_1001    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.54.3          py311hcafe171_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.22.6               h8e1006c_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.22.6               h98fc4e7_2    conda-forge
h5py                      3.9.0           py311hdd6beaf_0  
harfbuzz                  8.2.1                h3d44ed6_0    conda-forge
haversine                 2.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.12.1               h2b7332f_3  
humanize                  4.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
icu                       73.2                 h59595ed_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4             py311h06a4308_0  
imageio                   2.31.5             pyh8c1a49c_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2023.1.0         hdb19cb5_46305  
ipykernel                 6.26.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.15.0          py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
isoduration               20.11.0                  pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1          py311h06a4308_1    anaconda
jinja2                    3.1.2           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
joblib                    1.2.0           py311h06a4308_0  
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
jsonpointer               2.4                      pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.19.2                   pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema-specifications 2023.7.1                 pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-client            8.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              5.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-events            0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-lsp               2.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server            2.9.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-server-terminals  0.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-pygments       0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab-server         2.25.0                   pypi_0    pypi
kaggle                    1.5.16                   pypi_0    pypi
keras                     2.13.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py311h6a678d5_0  
krb5                      1.21.2               h659d440_0    conda-forge
lame                      3.100                h7b6447c_0  
lazy_loader               0.3             py311h06a4308_0  
lcms2                     2.15                 hb7c19ff_3    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1  
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20230125.3      cxx17_h59595ed_0    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h5eee18b_7  
libcap                    2.69                 h0f662aa_0    conda-forge
libclang                  15.0.7          default_h7634d5b_3    conda-forge
libclang13                15.0.7          default_h9986a30_3    conda-forge
libcups                   2.3.3                h4637d8d_4    conda-forge
libcurl                   8.4.0                hca28451_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.19                 hd590300_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20221030         h5eee18b_0  
libev                     4.33                 h7f8727e_1  
libevent                  2.1.12               hf998b51_1    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hcb278e6_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.4                h6a678d5_0  
libflac                   1.4.3                h59595ed_0    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 13.2.0               h807b86a_2    conda-forge
libgcrypt                 1.10.1               h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0               h00389a5_1  
libgfortran5              11.2.0               h1234567_1  
libglib                   2.78.0               hebfc3b9_0    conda-forge
libgpg-error              1.47                 h71f35ed_0    conda-forge
libgrpc                   1.54.3               hb20ce57_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libidn2                   2.3.4                h5eee18b_0  
libjpeg-turbo             3.0.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
libllvm14                 14.0.6               hdb19cb5_3  
libllvm15                 15.0.7               h5cf9203_3    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.57.0               h2d74bed_0  
libnsl                    2.0.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.5                h27cfd23_1  
libopus                   1.3.1                h7b6447c_0  
libpng                    1.6.39               h5eee18b_0  
libpq                     16.0                 hfc447b1_1    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.21.12              hfc55251_2    conda-forge
librosa                   0.10.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
libsndfile                1.2.2                hc60ed4a_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
libsqlite                 3.43.2               h2797004_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.11.0               h0841786_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              13.2.0               h7e041cc_2    conda-forge
libsystemd0               254                  h3516f8a_0    conda-forge
libtasn1                  4.19.0               h5eee18b_0  
libtiff                   4.6.0                ha9c0a0a_2    conda-forge
libunistring              0.9.10               h27cfd23_0  
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h7b6447c_0  
libvpx                    1.7.0                h439df22_0  
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h5eee18b_0  
libxcb                    1.15                 h7f8727e_0  
libxkbcommon              1.6.0                h5d7e998_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.5               h232c23b_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               14.0.6               h9e868ea_0  
llvmlite                  0.40.1          py311he621ea3_0  
lz4-c                     1.9.4                h6a678d5_0  
lzo                       2.10                 h7b6447c_2    anaconda
markdown                  3.4.1           py311h06a4308_0  
markupsafe                2.1.1           py311h5eee18b_0  
matplotlib                3.7.2           py311h38be061_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.7.2           py311ha02d727_0  
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
mistune                   3.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2023.1.0         h213fc3f_46343  
mkl-service               2.4.0           py311h5eee18b_1  
mkl_fft                   1.3.8           py311h5eee18b_0  
mkl_random                1.2.4           py311hdb19cb5_0  
mpg123                    1.32.3               h59595ed_0    conda-forge
msgpack-python            1.0.3           py311hdb19cb5_0  
multidict                 6.0.2           py311h5eee18b_0  
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0  
mysql-common              8.0.33               hf1915f5_5    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.33               hca2cd23_5    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
nbconvert                 7.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
nbformat                  5.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nccl                      2.19.3.1             h6103f9b_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  h6a678d5_0  
nest-asyncio              1.5.6           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
nettle                    3.7.3                hbbd107a_1  
notebook                  7.0.6                    pypi_0    pypi
notebook-shim             0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
nspr                      4.35                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.94                 h1d7d5a4_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.57.1          py311h96b013e_0    conda-forge
numexpr                   2.8.7           py311h65dcdc2_0    anaconda
numpy                     1.24.3          py311h08b1b3b_1  
numpy-base                1.24.3          py311hf175353_1  
oauthlib                  3.2.2           py311h06a4308_0  
onc                       2.3.5                    pypi_0    pypi
openh264                  2.1.1                h4ff587b_0  
openjpeg                  2.5.0                h488ebb8_3    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.4                hd590300_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
overrides                 7.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 23.1            py311h06a4308_0  
pandas                    2.1.1           py311ha02d727_0    anaconda
pandoc                    2.12                 h06a4308_3    anaconda
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pcre2                     10.40                hc3806b6_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3    anaconda
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003    anaconda
pillow                    10.1.0          py311ha6c5da5_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.3            py311h06a4308_0  
pixman                    0.42.2               h59595ed_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              3.10.0          py311h06a4308_0  
plotly                    5.18.0                     py_0    plotly
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
pooch                     1.7.0           py311h06a4308_0  
prometheus_client         0.14.1          py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
prompt-toolkit            3.0.36          py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
prompt_toolkit            3.0.36               hd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
protobuf                  4.21.12         py311hcafe171_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.0           py311h5eee18b_0    anaconda
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2    anaconda
pulseaudio-client         16.1                 hb77b528_5    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
py-cpuinfo                9.0.0           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0  
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
pydub                     0.25.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.15.1          py311h06a4308_1    anaconda
pyjwt                     2.4.0           py311h06a4308_0  
pyopenssl                 23.2.0          py311h06a4308_0  
pyparsing                 3.0.9           py311h06a4308_0  
pyqt                      5.15.9          py311hf0fb5b6_5    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 12.12.2         py311hb755f60_5    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.18.0          py311h5eee18b_0    anaconda
pysocks                   1.7.1           py311h06a4308_0  
pysoundfile               0.12.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pytables                  3.8.0           py311hb8ae3fc_3    anaconda
python                    3.11.6          hab00c5b_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2          py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
python-flatbuffers        2.0                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
python-json-logger        2.0.7                    pypi_0    pypi
python-slugify            8.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python-tzdata             2023.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
python_abi                3.11                    2_cp311    conda-forge
pytz                      2023.3.post1    py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
pyyaml                    6.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyzmq                     25.1.0          py311h6a678d5_0    anaconda
qt-main                   5.15.8              h82b777d_17    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.2.0           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
re2                       2023.03.02           h8c504da_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h5eee18b_0  
referencing               0.30.2                   pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.31.0          py311h06a4308_0  
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0  
rfc3339-validator         0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
rfc3986-validator         0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rpds-py                   0.10.6                   pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
scikit-learn              1.3.0           py311ha02d727_0  
scipy                     1.11.3          py311h08b1b3b_0    anaconda
send2trash                1.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                68.0.0          py311h06a4308_0  
sip                       6.7.12          py311hb755f60_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
snappy                    1.1.10               h9fff704_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.2.0           py311h06a4308_1    anaconda
soupsieve                 2.5                      pypi_0    pypi
soxr                      0.1.3                h0b41bf4_3    conda-forge
soxr-python               0.3.7           py311h1f0f07a_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.41.2               h5eee18b_0    anaconda
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
tbb                       2021.8.0             hdb19cb5_0  
tenacity                  8.2.2           py311h06a4308_0  
tensorboard               2.13.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tensorboard-data-server   0.7.0           py311h52d8a92_0  
tensorflow                2.13.1          cuda118py311h878bca4_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-base           2.13.1          cuda118py311h002e3ce_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-estimator      2.13.1          cuda118py311h4a64c31_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-gpu            2.13.1          cuda118py311h0240f8b_1    conda-forge
tensorflow-io             0.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 2.1.0           py311h06a4308_0  
terminado                 0.17.1          py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
testpath                  0.6.0           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
text-unidecode            1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0  
tinycss2                  1.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tk                        8.6.13               h2797004_0    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.3.3           py311h459d7ec_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.66.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.7.1           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
types-python-dateutil     2.8.19.14                pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.1.1                hd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
typing_extensions         4.1.1              pyh06a4308_0    anaconda
tzdata                    2023c                h04d1e81_0  
uri-template              1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.18         py311h06a4308_0  
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
webcolors                 1.13                     pypi_0    pypi
webencodings              0.5.1           py311h06a4308_1    anaconda
websocket-client          0.58.0          py311h06a4308_4    anaconda
werkzeug                  2.2.3           py311h06a4308_0  
wheel                     0.41.2          py311h06a4308_0  
widgetsnbextension        4.0.5           py311h06a4308_0    anaconda
wrapt                     1.14.1          py311h5eee18b_0  
x264                      1!157.20191217       h7b6447c_0  
xcb-util                  0.4.0                hd590300_1    conda-forge
xcb-util-image            0.4.0                h8ee46fc_1    conda-forge
xcb-util-keysyms          0.4.0                h8ee46fc_1    conda-forge
xcb-util-renderutil       0.3.9                hd590300_1    conda-forge
xcb-util-wm               0.4.1                h8ee46fc_1    conda-forge
xkeyboard-config          2.40                 hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.1.1                hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.4                h7391055_0    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.8.7                h8ee46fc_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h0b41bf4_2    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.11               hd590300_0    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h0b41bf4_1003    conda-forge
xorg-xf86vidmodeproto     2.3.1             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.4.2                h5eee18b_0  
yarl                      1.8.1           py311h5eee18b_0  
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0    anaconda
zlib                      1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
zlib-ng                   2.0.7                h5eee18b_0    anaconda
zstd                      1.5.5                hc292b87_0
```

Comment: probably an issue of mixing pip and conda in this way. Any reason why you install jupyter early with `pip` instead of conda? The traceback shows an error when code from `jupyter_events` (installed by `pip`) tries to use a function that is part of `python-fastjsonschema` (installed by `conda`).

Comment: @FlyingTeller - Yes. Jupyter's upgrade to Notebook 7 is not backward compatible, but I needed to use it. conda install -c conda-forge notebook has the 7.0.6 version for noarch, but 6.3 for everything else and I don't know how to force it to install the noarch 7.0.6 version, instead of the linux-64 6.3 version

Comment: You could try `conda install -c conda-forge notebook==7.0.6` in a fresh environment